# How do I count the number of collisions in a HashTable from a set of values?

Tags: java, hashtable

If given a set of number values and a HashTable size how could I simulate the number of collisions?

Comment: what research have you done so far?

Comment: The number of collisions depends on your hashing algorithm, so there is no single fits-all answer to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculate the hash values of your number values in your set and count the number of duplicate hash values.

A simple implementation of this may be:

```
List<Integer> yourValues = /* Your set of numbers */;
Map<Integer, Set<Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();
// Insert all elements into buckets based on their hash value
yourValues.forEach(value -> {
    if (!map.containsKey(value.hashCode()))
        map.put(value.hashCode(), new HashSet<>());
    map.get(value.hashCode()).add(value);
});
// Sum up the number of values in each bucket, subtract the number of buckets, so only duplicate values are counted
int collisions = map.values().stream().map(Set::size).reduce(0, Integer::sum) - map.size();
System.out.printf("Number of collisions: %d\n", collisions);
```

Comment: Thank you for this. However, I'm a bit confused about what data type yourObjects is. Could you possibly clarify?

Comment: It's a collection of integer values. Possibly a List<Integer> or Set<Integer>. I changed the answer.